# Multiple heredity of XML classes

Tags: java, c++, xml, inheritance, xsd

I've created XSD schema following conceptual model, but the model wants one class to inherit from two other classes. I know that basically it's impossible, on the other side I know that in some object oriented programming languages such as C++ or Java can handle it. 
I used following solution, but it's not heredity in the right meaning of the word: class inherits from one and has an attribute that instantiates  the other one. In the end I've had a class that inherits from another class and which has attribute, that is an instance of the other class.

```
<complexType name="BuildingType">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="otherSchema:BaseBuildingType">
            <sequence>
                <element name="buildingInfo" type="BuildingInfoType"/>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>

<complexType name="BuildingInfoType">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="anotherSchema:BuildingInfoType"/>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

According to the example above, complex type BuildingType shall inherit both from BaseBuildingType and BuildingInfoType. I've created an instance of BuildingInfo and set it up as an attribute of BuildingType. Is there any cleaner solution on how to inherit from two (or more classes)?

Comment: Did you solve this question?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this solution using `xs:group`

```
<xs:group name="BaseBuildingTypeGroup">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:group name="BuildingInfoTypeGroup">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:complexType name="BaseBuildingType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:group ref="BaseBuildingTypeGroup"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="BuildingInfoType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:group ref="BuildingInfoTypeGroup"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="BuildingType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:group ref="BuildingInfoTypeGroup"/>
        <xs:group ref="BaseBuildingTypeGroup"/>
        <xs:element name="date" type="xs:date"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: please can you be more specific? I don't get how can this help me to solve the problem

Comment: It is an old project of mine. In few words this proposal is a composition of one or more groups because does not exist a multiple hierarchy.